# Helm chart dependency from remote repo without helm dependency build command

Tags: kubernetes-helm

I have my custom application helm chart and i want to install a dependency chart from remote repo per say from https://charts.bitnami.com/bitnami.

I have some sort of automation which doesn't allow me to run `helm dependency build`, how can i install the dependency chart in this scenario; any work arounds?

Comment: Can you manually download the dependency chart and drop the `*.tgz` file in your application chart's `charts` directory?

Comment: Ahh, what if i want to upgrade my remote chart then?